# IOS Debug error (libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb))

Tags: ios, json

I was developing an ios translate application using the Yandex API. I followed this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

My ViewController.m file looks like this (I took out my api key):

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
#define TranslateText [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=APIKEY&lang=en-es&text=To+be,+or+not+to+be%3F"] //2

#import "ViewController.h"

@end
@interface NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress;
-(NSData*)toJSON;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress
{
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] ];
__autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error != nil) return nil;
return result;
}

-(NSData*)toJSON
{
NSError* error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error != nil) return nil;
return result;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: TranslateText];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
NSArray* TranslatedText = [json objectForKey:@"text"]; //2

NSLog(@"Text that was translated: %@", TranslatedText); //3

// 1) Get the latest loan
NSDictionary* ttext = [TranslatedText objectAtIndex:0];


// 3) Set the label appropriately
humanReadble.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ from %@ needs another",
                     [ttext objectForKey:@"name"],
                     [(NSDictionary*)[ttext objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"]];

}

@end
```

When I run my app (iphone 6.1 simulator), it gives me this error and the app pauses.

```
2013-07-31 09:57:51.111 Translate[76046:c07] Text that was translated: (
"Ser, o no ser?"
)
2013-07-31 09:57:51.146 Translate[76046:c07] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71d1ef0
2013-07-31 09:57:51.150 Translate[76046:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71d1ef0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d1c4bd 0x1c80bbc 0x1c8094e 0x2c57 0x10e26b0 0xb0e765 0x1c14f3f 0x1c1496f 0x1c37734 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1beb7e3 0x1beb668 0x12ffc 0x1f5d 0x1e85)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

It also opens up a file main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

It points this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

and says Thread 1: **signal SIGABRT**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the NSLog output it seems that

```
NSArray* TranslatedText = [json objectForKey:@"text"];
```

is an array of *strings*, not an array of *dictionaries*. So you should replace

```
NSDictionary* ttext = [TranslatedText objectAtIndex:0];
```

by

```
NSString* ttext = [TranslatedText objectAtIndex:0];
```

and replace `[ttext objectForKey:@"name"]` by `ttext`.

Comment: When I change `[ttext objectForKey:@"name"]` to `ttext`, I get the error **Expected identifier**. When I type in `[ttext: @"name"]`, I get the error **No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the sector "."**. What is this error caused by?

Comment: @Firelight: `[ttext: @"name"]` does not make sense. Just `ttext` should be correct. Can you update your question with the modified code and the exact error message?

Comment: I changed `[ttext: @"name"]` to `ttext` and I got no error message. Before, I used `[ttext]` and it gave me the error. I now get no message and the application works.